# is it possible to run a piece of external php code after each php statement?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

The problem is that I must catch situation when some variable (and I don't know it's name, that is I don't know where this value first arises) matches some record in database. The way I think it could be done is to run after each statement an external code against array of local and remote variables. In that external code would be a simple foreach loop and db query, the script would then output line number where given situation happened.

Is this possible with xdebug ?

Comment: can you re-write the question so it makes some kind of sense

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you debugging your code? Please rewrite your question more clearly.

Comment: Yes I am debugging my code. And I want to avoid to look in each one variable in the debugger to spot when it is becoming wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you want to set breakpoints.

Comment: In some kind of way, yes, breakpoints, but on every statement, not by hand, and on every such 'breakpoint' (since everything is breakpoint then) I want to run external code.

Comment: i...am...so...confused by this question

Comment: I am so confused that you all are confused. I have no idea what is confusing in here.

Comment: what you want to do is unclear (obviously English is not your first language), why you want to do it is missing, an example of code is also missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function for that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php more documentation on ticks is http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php here.

Comment: Well, kind of, this is very close but is it possible with Xdebug, where I have variables array to use in function ?